# How to clear line or password prompt in Windows PowerShell like CTRL+U in Linux?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, prompt

When using Linux, you can use `CTRL+U` for clearing the current prompt. This is very useful, when entering a password and you need to clear the current (hidden) password, to write it again, for example because you made a typo.

However, this will not work out-of-the-box in Windows PowerShell, using Windows Terminal. When you press `CTRL+U`, you will see `^U` instead of clearing the line. Of course, this will not work for password prompt also, like in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`.

Which process would responsible for this feature? `Windows Terminal`, `PowerShell`, `PSReadLine`? I guess, it's not `ssh.exe`.

Is there any known way to achieve this feature?

Comment: I normally hit `esc`.

Comment: This does not work for Password Prompts:

C:\Users\sebastian> ssh pi@10.8.0.2
pi@10.8.0.2's password: # Pressed ESC + Password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@10.8.0.2's password: # Entered Correct Password directly
Linux rpi-router 5.15.84-v8+ #1613 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 5 12:03:08 GMT 2023 aarch64

Comment: Password prompt is for each application on their own. That's not handled by the console in any way. To clear the command on the command-prompt it's `esc` anything else is up to the app developer/console library they depend on.

Comment: Once connected to the other end, it's up to the receiving end to interpret what's being entered. Behavior may differ between Windows Terminal and Classic terminal as Classic terminal has a few backwards compact additions to keep in mind.

Comment: PS more a SuperUser question.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested with password prompts, but what comes pretty close to what I am used from Linux terminals is this binding:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+u -Function BackwardDeleteLine
```

See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions) for other available functions.

In contrast to `ESC`, it only removes the part in front of the cursor and keeps the remaining input.